# Jest configure typescript without webpack

Tags: typescript, jestjs

Well I'm writing some NPM module with typescript, but i'm not using Webpack to compile the scripts.

how should I configure jest to run properly with typescript files?

```
// test.spec.ts
import {calc} from './index'

test('shoud...', () => {
  expect(calc()).toBeDefined()
})
```

```
// index.ts
import {calc} from './index'

const calc = (a, b) => {
  return a + b
}
```

I got this error:

> testMatch: **/__tests__/**/*.js?(x),**/?(*.)+(spec|test).js?(x) - 0 matches
>     testPathIgnorePatterns: /node_modules/ - 9 matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Step 1: Install**

```
npm i jest @types/jest ts-jest -D
```

**Explanation:**

- Install jest framework (jest)
- Install the types for jest (@types/jest)
- Install the TypeScript preprocessor for jest (ts-jest) which allows
  jest to transpile TypeScript on the fly and have source-map support
  built in.
- Save all of these to your dev dependencies (testing is almost always
  a npm dev-dependency)

**Step 2: Configure Jest**

Add the following `jest.config.js` file to the root of your project:

```
module.exports = {
  "roots": [
    "<rootDir>/src"
  ],
  "transform": {
    "^.+\\.tsx?$": "ts-jest"
  },
}
```

**Explanation:**

- We always recommend having all TypeScript files in a src folder in
  your project.
- We assume this is true and specify this using the roots option. The transform config just tells jest to use ts-jest for ts / tsx
  files. jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#transform-object-string-string

**refernce**: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/testing/jest.html