# Configuring Jest with Typescript

Tags: typescript, jestjs

I am pretty new to TypeScript and I was experimenting with [Jest](https://jestjs.io/) (unit test framework).
I was trying to make just a little and simple test, but I got a *strange* error.

#### Setup

I created a file `position.ts` in folder `/src` with the following code:

```
export class Position {
  constructor(public x: number, public y: number) {}
}
```

Then in folder `/tests` I put a file called `position.test.ts`:

```
import {Position} from './position';

test('basic', () => {
  let p = new Position(1, 2);
  expect(p.x).toBe(1);
  expect(p.y).toBe(2);
});
```

And I have created a file in the project root called `jest.config.ts` with the following content:

```
module.exports = {
  'roots': ['<rootDir>/src'],
  'transform': {'^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'},
}
```

My `tsconfig.json` contains:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./dist", 
    "rootDir": "./",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  }
}
```

#### Issue

When I run: `tsc` no errors are reported.
When I run: `npx jest` I get the following error:

```
 FAIL  tests/position.test.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    /home/killkrt/developer/Atomts/tests/position.test.ts:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,global,jest){import { Position } from '../src/position';
                                                                                             ^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

How can I solve it?

I would like to keep my source code in `/src` folder, tests in `/tests` and *compiled* js in `/dist`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631104/jest-configure-typescript-without-webpack/56631145#56631145, please take a look.

Comment: @LidorAvitan I have tried your link (that's basically what I was doing). Anyway I found a strange thing. I have tried with my Windows 10 machine and it works, while the same exact procedure doesn't work (same issue as already reported) on a fresh Arch Linux installation! Mmmh...

Comment: Have you found the answer? I'm facing the same problem. Ubuntu

Comment: @Anna no :-( and I am not working anymore on that project, so no news

Comment: There's similar issue. This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59834203/6269336

Answer (score 0):

In my case I saw this error when I tried to run the tests using "Run" option in WebStorm.

But it works when I just ran command from console.

So the reason was - WebStorm used wrong jest configuration file by default. I changed it to point to the right one and this solve the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below steps:

```sh
yarn add ts-jest -D
```

then in your `jest.config.js` file put following:

```js
module.exports = {
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.ts?$': 'ts-jest',
  },
};
```