# Jest complains about Typescript syntax

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

When I run `yarn test` Jest throws an error that says

> 'Const declarations' require an initialization value.

Which is not what I'm doing!

```
> 4 | const config: HardhatUserConfig = {
    |             ^
  5 |   solidity: "0.8.9",
  6 |   paths: {
  7 |     artifacts: "./src/artifects",
```

I think it is obvious that `jest` is having problem with TS syntax.
**How can I fix that?**

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58261143/438992, https://stackoverflow.com/q/56631104/438992, etc?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Jest configure typescript without webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56631104/jest-configure-typescript-without-webpack)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`ts-jest`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-jest).

- Install ts-jest: `npm install ts-jest -D`
- Update your jest config to use: `preset: 'ts-jest'`

You still run your tests the same way - just run `jest`.

Comment: I got `TypeError: Jest: a transform must export a "process" function.`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure why that would be happening. Make sure to follow the instructions on the ts-jest project page and report back here (if you don't mind).

Comment: Sure!‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎‏‏‎ ‎

Comment: Thanks it worked! The problem with the second error was that I should use major versions for both `Jest` and  `ts-jest`